# Cant add Testers on iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2, app-store-connect

For some reason i can't add any of my users as testers for my apps. I can only add myself as tester.

• I logged in as to iTunes connect as admin
• Go to users - I see 3 users and they all confirmed their emails
• i go to TEST users and see the same 3 sets
• So i go back to the app and click the test flight tab
• Click on internal testing (i don't have any external testers btw)
• I see ONE internal tester, so i click the PLUS Button
• So i get a popup with the following

Up to 25 iTunes Connect users with the Admin, App Manager, Developer, Marketer or Legal role can be added as internal testers.

And only the first tester which is admin and which i used before

I found similar questions but none of their answers fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the user has an appropriate role, and that the user is enabled to access the app you are trying to test.

From the Users and Roles option in iTunes Connect, check that the user you are trying to add has "All Apps" or the Name of your APP in the apps column of that table.

If it doesn't, you need to give that user permission to the app through the user's role tab, as shown here:

[image]